# During Lead conversion how to copy Standard Email to a custom email field under Contact

Tags: community, administration

I'm changing the Lead conversion process to instead of copying standard Email from Lead to standard Email in Contact.
The desired process is to copy Email to a custom field under Contact called Primary Email(Primary_Email__c). In the screenshot below only shows how to map Custom Fields.

[image: Lead Mapping]

Is there a way to achieve this without a flow/trigger?

These are a few articles that I've read during my research:

- [Map Custom Lead Fields for Lead Conversion](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_mapleads.htm&type=5)
- [Lead Conversion Field Mapping](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lead_conversion_mapping.htm&type=5)
- [What happens when I convert leads?](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.faq_leads_what_happens_when.htm&type=5)

Comment: The only way to do this is with a custom Flow or trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following David's Cheng suggestion I've created a Flow on Contact to be fired on its Creation. It copies the value from Email to Primary Email given that Email is filled out every time a Lead is converted.

**Flow Overview**
[image: Flow Overview]

**Record-Triggered Flow**
[image: Record-Triggered Flow]

**UpdatePrimaryEmail action**
[image: UpdatePrimaryEmail action]